# How to get JavaScript to read from a HTML rather than hardcoded data?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, frontend

here is my code

html:

```
<div ng-app="myFirstApp" ng-controller="countriesController">

    <p> Search for a country: </p>

    <p><input type="text" ng-model="test"></p>

    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="x in countryList | filter:test">
        {{ x.country }}
      </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('myFirstApp', []);

app.controller('countriesController', function($scope) {
    $scope.countryList = [
        {country:'Argentina'},
        {country:'Brazil'},
        {country:'Chile'},
        {country:'Colombia'},
        {country:'Paraguay'},
        {country:'Panama'},
        {country:'Andorra'}
    ];


});
```

so far i can type into a box and it will return only countries matching the text.
i would like to do things. firstly, as seen above the country list is hardcoded into the javascript. if i had a standard unordered list in the html file like so:

```
<ul id="countryList">
    <li>Argentina</li>
    <li>Brazil</li>
    <li>Chile</li>
    <li>Colombia</li>
    <li>Paraguay</li>
    <li>Panama</li>
    <li>Andorra</li>
</ul>
```

how can i get the script to use this data rather than it being hardcoded into JS.
the other smaller query is how do you get js to do different patterns. for example if i type in 'a' at the moment, all the countries with 'a' in are returned. but i only want countries beginning with A to be returned in this instance.

thanks

Comment: So you want a "hard-coded" List in your DOM (Markup) and than read it out with JS ? than why using angularjs in the first place? -> You could do this just with jQuery or VanillaJS

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you're using angularjs for this purpose, I would do this differently:

- Create a Service for Country (a great introduction to his topic is http://kirkbushell.me/when-to-use-directives-controllers-or-services-in-angular/ )
- Then add the array into the service (or use $http and create a .json file where you manage the country list)
- In your controller inherit the service
- Call Country.get(...) which returns the list

For your filter:
If you want a 100% match you could just use "true" as a second parameter for your filter.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in countryList | filter:test:true">
    {{ x.country }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Otherwise you have to write a filter-function (e.g. docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter , [AngularJs, filter case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082017/angularjs-filter-case-insensitive)):

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in countryList | myFilter:test">
    {{ x.country }}
  </li>
</ul>

app.filter("myFilter", function(){
  return function(items, test){
      var returnItems = items;
       if(test === "") {
         returnItems = items;
       }
    else {
      returnItems = items.filter(function(element, index,array) {
        if(element.country.indexOf(test) !== -1)
        return true;
      });
    }
    return returnItems;
  };
});
```

EDIT: Here is a jsbin (working): https://jsbin.com/ruheditude/6/edit?html,js,output

My fault was to use $scope, you have to use $app. Updated code example

Comment: this answer is great, just one more thing before I mark it. where do i wack the $scope.myFilter thing. i have put it in my js code but so far it is not being picked up

Comment: Updated a bit (as it was sort of prototyping before), here is the jsbin https://jsbin.com/ruheditude/6/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, data has to be defined somewhere. At least in a database, or you can generate this data. Either way, as long as you get data external to the application, to you it is dynamic.

So you can create .json file and grab that the same way, I have called the URL to get data. The reason why I have moved the data retrieval is so that you can re-use the code somewhere else in your application. This is a good practice for you when developing angular applications.

To achieve your 'Starts With' behaviour - I implemented a filter which is explained below.

I have implemented a complete example of this. Since it was great for me as learning as well. Below is the use of that filter, I created.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="user in users | startsWith:searchText | orderBy: 'name' ">
        {{user.name}} | {{user.company.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

[JSFiddle: StartWith](http://jsfiddle.net/CodeHawkz/9cgg1sf3/)