# AngularJS filter list case insensitive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a list of subjects and i want to search through my list and return valid results but it is case senstive and doesnt return the correct results

```
var subjects = [
  {id: '1', name: 'Maths'}, 
  {id: '2', name: 'English'},
  {id: '3', name: 'Physics'}
]; 

var returnValue = { items: [] };
subjects.forEach(function(item){

  if (item.name.indexOf(query) > -1 ){
     returnValue.items.push(item);
  }
  else if (item.id.indexOf(query) > -1 ){
     returnValue.items.push(item);
  }
});
console.log(returnValue)
```

So for example if i enter the text 'm', when it searches the list of subjects it should return Maths but right now it returns nil but if i input 'M', then it returns the subject Maths.

Any help on solving this? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always convert the comparison values to lowercase and then compare.

```
ar subjects = [
  {id: '1', name: 'Maths'}, 
  {id: '2', name: 'English'},
  {id: '3', name: 'Physics'}
]; 

var returnValue = { items: [] };
subjects.forEach(function(item){

  var itemNameLower = item.name.toLowerCase();
  var queryLower = query.toLowerCase();

  if (itemNameLower.indexOf(queryLower) > -1 ){
     returnValue.items.push(item);
  }
  else if (item.id.indexOf(queryLower) > -1 ){
     returnValue.items.push(item);
  }
});
console.log(returnValue)
```

Comment: that would have been my answer

Comment: @avijit thnks but i would prefer case insensitive rather than doing this

Comment: @Gianmarco is there no other way to handle this, angularjs style?

Comment: @KingsleySimon You may be looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082017/angularjs-filter-case-insensitive

Comment: probably using a filter `item in items | filter : searchText : false`

Comment: @Gianmarco The default value is already `false`, it need not be set explicitly.  `ng-repeat="item in items | filter : searchText"` should also work in an insensitive manner.

Comment: just give it a shot and verify ;)

Comment: @AvijitGupta i cant use filter due to the plugin tht i am using to execute this.