# angularjs filter issue when using multiple items in filter like capital & small letters

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Working with angularjs 1.6, issue with filter

I tried to apply toLowerCase() on array of items but no use. Can somebody help me how to tackle this issue in fitler.

Here is the code,

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search by name" ng-model="peer.searchString">
<div class="item ui very compact popup-element" ng-repeat="item in peer.healthList | filter: {'ServiceName': peer.searchString, 'Name': peer.Name}">
    <div style="display:flex; width:100%;cursor: pointer;" ng-click="onItemClick(item,peer, $event);">
        <div class="ui avatar image" ng-class="item.Status"></div>
        <div class="content">
        <div class="header popup popup-element exportable">{{item.ServiceName ? item.ServiceName : item.Name}} </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right floated meta">{{item.Status}}</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Here is the list items,

ABC, BBA, abc, and DCa ... which are retrieved from the API and populating either or not.

```
{{item.ServiceName ? item.ServiceName : item.Name}}
```

Little complex here to filter out. It only filters non capitalized words, remaining simply unfiltered.

when try to search only 'abc' 'll be filtering, about remaining items seems won't be there in list it treats.

Thanks,

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: When i search normal list items without capital letters will be filtering, where as list items with capital letter's won't filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of, [AngularJs, filter case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082017/angularjs-filter-case-insensitive)

```
<div class="item ui very compact popup-element" ng-repeat="item in peer.healthList | filter: {'ServiceName': peer.searchString} : false">
```

This works!

Comment: It won't, i've solved the issue with an alternate...

Comment: It does. Take a look at this plunker, http://plnkr.co/edit/9FjIKhE8XwYFYkYYaCE2?p=preview

Comment: It's not about irrespective of context, the problem i met won't solved.. rather i'm working with multiple filter items, whereas data was populated simultaneously. So it solved by doing at the controller js file.

Comment: Alright! Glad, you resolved it. But the question title, tags, description does not seem to support your problem definition in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for that, updated with problem specific.

Answer (score 0):

It's working when i variable the response data with another variable in controller..

```
o.displayName = o.ServiceName ? o.ServiceName : o.Name;
```

I've used displayName as ServiceName in HTML replicates the exact. The actual problem was multiple filter variables won't working.

Thanks